# Emacs / OSX / Calendar-Mode: Ideas for more spacing between dates

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm looking for some ideas please to get some more spacing between dates in calendar-mode using Emacs on OSX 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard).  Also, any suggestions regarding how to make this `buffer-local` (if possible) would be greatly appreciated.

I have a feeling that if I hack the source to create two (2) spaces between calendar dates, I'm going to be in for a world of hurt resulting from unforeseen complications.  However, that is essentially what I'd like to see -- spaces between horizontal *and* vertical rows equal to 2 spaces.

My default is:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :background "black" :foreground "white"
  :font "Courier" :height 180)
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`line-spacing` "*automatically becomes buffer-local when set*".  There are a vareity of ways to use something like `(setq line-spacing 3)` -- e.g., with hooks that run after the calendar is generated.  I chose to modify the initial `define-derived-mode . . .` by adding `(setq line-spacing 3)`.

The other settings that control calendar appearances include, but are not limited to:  `calendar-left-margin`, `calendar-column-width`, `calendar-day-header-width`, `calendar-day-digit-width`, `calendar-intermonth-header`, `calendar-intermonth-text`.